# Counts, percentages and scaling in clustering

Tags: clustering, standardization

I am working in a clustering.

I have a dataset with the accesses of a series of subjects to a facility (each row register the subject ID and the date/time of the access)

I can, for example, count the number of accesses on Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday... As a result, after the aggregation, I have a dataset with one line for each user, with the count of accesses for each day of the week as features

But later, I can calculate the percentages. For one subject, what percentage of acceses correspond to monday? After working with the data, for each subject I have:

- The total access count for that week day, which tells me if a subjet uses my facility more often than other subjets this week day
- The percentage related to the total accesses for the week, which tells me which is the favorite day of the subjet for using my facility

Both are different features, giving me different information. Now, I need to standarize/scale:

- The counts MUST be somehow standarized, so the count for each day of the week stay in the same range for all users. I can use standarization (mean 0, deviation 1), or min-max scaling (i.e, to values 0-1), so the distribution shape is maintained, which does not occur in standarization. Which should I use?
- In percentages, all values are in range 0-1 (the same range than using min-max scaling), but theese percentages are related to the the rest of week days (same row, same subject), not the rest of values in the column (the other subjects). Should I apply an scale/standarization through that column?

Thanks!

Comment: Try all three ways of transforming the data, and see which one scores the best. It is routine in unsupersived machine learning to try multiple variations of a procedure to see which scores the best. You do need to be cautious that you may be overfitting in the extremes, however. And since it is unsupervised you don't have cross-validation.